# Is it possible to search within Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I have an Android application that we are porting over to Honeycomb/Android 3.0 and we are using `Fragment`s in our new interface.

I have search working via the widget as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).

The problem is, the widget doesn't pop up any more when using `Fragment`s.  So the question is how do I get search to be used with `Fragment`s?

Or how can I replace this line to be used with `Fragment`s?

```
getActivity().onSearchRequested();
```

Comment: none.  Had to create my own search mechanism.

Comment: this could be the answer of your question: [see the third answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230893/android-search-with-fragments

Comment: @Kid24 check my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/24940111/1276636

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem using interface/callbacks.

In my `MainActivity`, I write a callback interface:

```
private SearchRequestedCallback mSearchRequestedCallback;
public void setSearchRequestedCallback(SearchRequestedCallback callback) {
    mSearchRequestedCallback = callback;
}
public interface SearchRequestedCallback {
    void onSearchRequested();
}
```

In my `Fragment`, I set the callback in the `onStart()` and unset it in the `onStop()`:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getActivity().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSearchRequestedCallback(new SearchRequestedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchRequested() {
            addFilter();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSearchRequestedCallback(null);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The `SearchManager` is implemented to work with `Activity`s, not `Fragment`s. See [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7230893/844882) for more information.