# Android ActionbarSherlock SearchView

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Can we implement SeachView in Android 2.2 using ActionbarSherlock.

I am using following code, it is working fine in 3.0 but not working in 2.2

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    // set up a listener for the refresh item


        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // Do something
                System.out.println("onQueryTextChange----------");
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // Do something
                System.out.println("onQueryTextSubmit----------");
                return true;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

   return true;
     }
```

I am getting following error on 2.2

```
    at 01-23 17:31:53.230: W/MenuInflater(20214):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-23 17:31:53.230: W/MenuInflater(20214):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuInflaterImpl$MenuState.newInstance(MenuInflaterImpl.java:533)
01-23 17:31:53.230: W/MenuInflater(20214):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuInflaterImpl$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflaterImpl.java:497)
01-23 17:31:53.230: W/MenuInflater(20214):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuInflaterImpl$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflaterImpl.java:515)
01-23 17:31:53.230: W/MenuInflater(20214):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuInflaterImpl.parseMenu(MenuInflaterImpl.java:238)
01-23 17:31:53.230: W/MenuInflater(20214):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuInflaterImpl.inflate(MenuInflaterImpl.java:164)
01-23 17:31:53.230: W/MenuInflater(20214):  at com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styledactionbar.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:99)
01-23 17:31:53.230: W/MenuInflater(20214):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:601)
01-23 17:31:53.230: W/MenuInflater(20214):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:706)
```

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991980/actionbarsherlock-searchview-setonquerytextlistener/15050518#15050518). I have not tested it with Versions lower than 3.0.

Answer (score 12):

A small update:

- Jake Wharton is currently working on ActionBarSherlock 4.2.0 in `dev` branch and has `SearchView` backported there. It has limited functionality (most notable - no support for `SearchableInfo`). But he is working on expanding functionality.
- I didn't know about Jake Wharton's intentions on backporting `SearchView` and did my version of backport (can be found on github: [abs-search-view](https://github.com/inazaruk/abs-search-view)). My version also does not support `SearchableInfo`.

These two implementations were done in mostly the same way. They use much of the same code taken from AOSP. But there are some notable differences.

- ActionBarSherlock backport supports suggestions adapter
- ActionBarSherlock backport does not fallback on original `SearchView` implementation on systems with API 11 and up (i.e. it's the same code with pros and cons on all platforms).
- My version does not support suggestions adapter (it can be added though).
- My version has limited functionality on systems before API 11 (where backport version of code is used) and on API 11 and higher everything fallbacks to original native version of `SearchView` and all features are supported the way they are described in documentation.

Personally, I'd recommend sticking with ActionBarSherlock version (it's just easier that way). And use my library only if you need this fully functional behavior on systems with API 11 and up.

Comment: Is SearchableInfo still not supported? 
I.E Can one not follow this tutorial under "Configuring the search widget" http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Thanks

Comment: As of date 06-12-2012, SearchView is implemented in Ver 4.2 of ABS.

Answer (score 12):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/layout_menu_search"
    android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, from what I have read and tried, ActionBarSherlock does not support the SearchView widget.

Android is set to release a backwards compatibility package in the future supporting this, but who knows when that will be.

See this link from the man himself:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/70

Comment: An alternative is to case out your search view widget based on the OS version. Create your own search view widget for pre-honeycomb devices and use the default for API-11+.

Comment: `SearchView` is a very advanced widget. It's backport would not be trivial. This may happen in the future as the linked issue says but it's not a priority for me. Would be perfect for a contribution by someone though...

Comment: SearchView is implemented in ABS in ver 4.2.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, so I created a custom SearchView. Maybe you want to check it out at https://github.com/benjaminmock/MenuItemSearchAction