# Action bar with Search View. Reverse compatibility issues

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I am building a sample app to demonstrate SearchView with filter and other Action Bar items.
I am able to successfully run this app on 4.2(Nexus 7). But it is not running on 2.3. I googled about the issue. Came to know that i should use SherLock Action bar. I just went to http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html, downloaded the zip file and added the library as informed in the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY&feature=player_embedde by WiseManDesigns. But still I am unable to figure out the issue.

Here is my code:

SearchViewActionBar.java

```
public class SearchViewActionBar extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener 
{
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private TextView mStatusView;
    int mSortMode = -1;
    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    protected CharSequence[] _options = { "Wild Life", "River", "Hill Station", "Temple", "Bird Sanctuary", "Hill", "Amusement Park"};
    protected boolean[] _selections =  new boolean[ _options.length ];


    private final String[] mStrings = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);
       // mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mStrings));
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        //setupSearchView();
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
        //mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.cheese_hunt_hint));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchview_in_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
       //setupSearchView(searchItem);
       setupSearchView();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        if (mSortMode != -1) 
        {
            Drawable icon = menu.findItem(mSortMode).getIcon();
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort).setIcon(icon);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String c="Category";
        String s=(String) item.getTitle();
        if(s.equals(c))
        {
            System.out.println("same");
            showDialog( 0 );
        }
        //System.out.println(s);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item: " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog( int id ) 
    {
        return 
        new AlertDialog.Builder( this )
            .setTitle( "Category" )
            .setMultiChoiceItems( _options, _selections, new DialogSelectionClickHandler() )
            .setPositiveButton( "SAVE", new DialogButtonClickHandler() )
            .create();
    }


    public class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener
    {
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected )
        {
            Log.i( "ME", _options[ clicked ] + " selected: " + selected );
        }
    }


    public class DialogButtonClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int clicked )
        {
            switch( clicked )
            {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    printSelectedPlanets();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void printSelectedPlanets()
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++ ){
            Log.i( "ME", _options[ i ] + " selected: " + _selections[i] );
        }
    }

    public void onSort(MenuItem item) 
    {
        mSortMode = item.getItemId();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }


    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) 
    {
        mStatusView.setText("Query = " + query + " : submitted");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onClose() 
    {
        mStatusView.setText("Closed!");
        return false;
    }

    protected boolean isAlwaysExpanded() 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: An easy way to see if its a compatibility issue is to change your project build target to 2.3 and see if you get any errors.

Comment: I'd use ActionBarSherlock, as it has SearchView implementation for backwards compatibility to API 7 or 8. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971776/android-actionbarsherlock-searchview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use ActionBarSherlock. To do this your activity needs to extends and ActionBarSherlock component. Something more like this:

`MySearchActivity extends SherlockActivity {}`

or if you want to use the build in list API's you could just do this:

`MySearchActivity extends SherlockListActivity {}`

then in the res/menu folder create activity_mysearch.xml file with something like this in it:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
</menu>
```

Now have your activity implement OnQueryTextListener. In the onCreateOptionsMenu do:

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_mysearch, menu);
MenuItem searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchViewMenuItem.getActionView();
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

You can now use the

```
onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
onQueryTextChange(String newText)
```

methods to query your list and update your list view item. You can also add a filter to the adapter and create an interface that notifies the activity to invalidate the list views after the adapter's data set has changed.