# Actionbarsherlock searchview: setOnQueryTextListener

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I'm trying to make a filter in a List using ActionBarSherlock's search view. The code I currently have is the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.building_search, menu);

    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() 
    {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) 
        {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            listAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) 
        {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            listAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

These are my imports:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import be.ugent.zeus.hydra.AbstractSherlockActivity;
import be.ugent.zeus.hydra.R;
import be.ugent.zeus.hydra.data.caches.AssociationsCache;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;
import com.dd.plist.NSArray;
import com.dd.plist.NSDictionary;
import com.dd.plist.NSString;
import com.dd.plist.XMLPropertyListParser;
import com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

Most of it works: in my actionbar, I get a search icon, which is clickable and expands the searchview. What, however, doesn't work is the actual listener. I've put breakpoints inside both methods, but when I debug, nothing happens. The program doesn't break and nothing gets filtered and I can't figure out why.

Does anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post your imports in this file?

Comment: I added them to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every other answer contained a bit of truth, but didn't answer the question fully, I'll create my own answer.

When this issue was created - half a year ago - ABS did not fully implement the SearchView functionality. As of ABS 4.2.0, this has been implemented.

My full implementation, by following the ABS sample app, can be found [here](https://github.com/ZeusWPI/hydra/pull/139/files).

Answer (score 5):

This is how I implemented my search with ActionBarSherlock:

In the menu.xml under the res/menu folder, I added an icon:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" 
      android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"/>
```

I then created a class which is responsible for recieving the action search queries and presenting the data:

```
    public class SearchActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Log.d(TAG, "This is the search view activity");
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.search_result_layout);
            }


    private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
        if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())){
        searcdhQuery = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        //here we shall do e search..
        Log.d(TAG, "This is the search query:" + searcdhQuery);

                    //This is the asynctask query to connect to the database...
        String[] value = {searcdhQuery};
        SearchQuery searchQuery = new SearchQuery();
        searchQuery.execute(value);
        }
        }

            @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onNewIntent(intent);
         handleIntent(intent);
        }
        }
```

In the manifest, this activity is included with Search and View filters as Shown below:

```
    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

Also in the manifest, don't forget the meta-data in the application showing the default search of the activity, as shown below:

```
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                    android:value=".SearchActivity" />
```

Finally in the onCreateOptionsMenu, be sure to add the search configuration by associating it with the search service:

```
    //associating the searchable configuration with the search service...
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Nothing is required in the onOptionsItemSelected method.

This worked perfectly for me. In case you need more details please find more information from the [Search View Demo](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html) in the actionBarSherlock and The [developers tutorial on the Setting a Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: And where do you attach an onQueryTextListener? I want to update the list I'm displaying while the user is typing. I don't see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: I did not implement on query text listner, but I think, like @Luksprog mentioned below, It should be attached to the SearchView, while configuring the onOptionsItemSelected method.

Answer (score 3):

In case you haven't found an answer,this is how I'm doing it (I am using ActionBarSherlock):

- add an entry to the menu declaration

  ```
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
      android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
      android:icon="@drawable/wfm_menu_search"
      android:showAsAction="always|withText|collapseActionView"
      android:title="@string/menu_search"/>
  ```
- In your activity override"onCreateOptionsMenu" to inflate your menu and associate your SearcView :

  ```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
      getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
      this.refreshMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh);

      this.searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
      this.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
          // collapse the view ?
          menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).collapseActionView();
          return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
          // search goes here !!
          // listAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
          return false;
      }

  });
  ```

That's it, no other activities. Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Is that your full code? Right now in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` you create a `SearchView` and assign to it a `OnQueryTextListener` but that is all you do with it. I don't see in your code where you add this `SearchView` to the inflated menu.

As you say you see the widget on the screen, I'm assuming you have declared the widget in the `R.menu.building_search` file, in which case you should look for that widget(which doesn't have a listener set on it so no action is performed) and not declare a new one(which will not interact with the user):

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
```

(This is from the Search guide on the android developer site, if I'm not mistaken this should work for ActionBarSherlock as well).