# Android SearchView not working in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, searchview, android-search

I am trying to implement a searchview that is only required in one fragment.  It will filter on a listview.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import com.alcontrol.atmis.anticimex.R;
import com.alcontrol.atmis.anticimex.model.ListViewsModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SalesParts extends Fragment {

public SalesParts() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
ArrayList<ListViewsModel> listofOrderSelectedArray = new ArrayList<ListViewsModel>();
ArrayList<ListViewsModel> listofOrdersArray = new ArrayList<ListViewsModel>();
SimpleAdapter adapter;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter2;
ListView mListView;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items;


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    listofOrdersArray.add(new ListViewsModel(101, "Order Title 1",""));
    listofOrdersArray.add(new ListViewsModel(102, "Order Title 2",""));
    listofOrdersArray.add(new ListViewsModel(103, "Order Title 3",""));
    listofOrdersArray.add(new ListViewsModel(104, "Order Title 4",""));
    listofOrdersArray.add(new ListViewsModel(105, "Order Title 5",""));
    listofOrdersArray.add(new ListViewsModel(106, "Order Title 6",""));
    listofOrdersArray.add(new ListViewsModel(107, "Order Title 7",""));
    listofOrdersArray.add(new ListViewsModel(108, "Order Title 8",""));
    listofOrdersArray.add(new ListViewsModel(109, "Order Title 9",""));
    listofOrdersArray.add(new ListViewsModel(110, "SOrder Title 10",""));

    mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.salespartsList);
    mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.typeFindSalesPart);
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);


    items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> listItem;

    for (int i = 0; i < listofOrdersArray.size(); i++) {
        ListViewsModel selectedDescription = listofOrdersArray.get(i);
        listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        listItem.put("itemTitle",selectedDescription.itemTitle);
        listItem.put("itemID",selectedDescription.itemId);
        listItem.put("addBtn", "");
        items.add(listItem);
    }

    ListView addSelectedItems = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.salespartsListSelected);
    arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.selected_salespart_item,R.id.itemTitle, listofOrderSelectedArray) {

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            // get filled view from SimpleAdapter
            View itemView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            // find our button there
            View addButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemDeleteBtn);

            // set a tag to get button position in array (used to get values when button is clicked
            addButton.setTag(String.valueOf(position));

            // add an onClickListener
            addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String tagName = (String) v.getTag();
                    int arrayPosition = Integer.valueOf(tagName);

                    //remove selected item from the list of sales parts to choose from
                    listofOrderSelectedArray.remove(arrayPosition);
                    arrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            return itemView;
        }
    };
    addSelectedItems.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), items, R.layout.salespart_item, new String[]{"itemTitle", "addBtn"}, new int[]{R.id.itemTitle, R.id.itemAddBtn}) {

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            // get filled view from SimpleAdapter
            View itemView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            // find our button there
            View addButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemAddBtn);

            // set a tag to get button position in array (used to get values when button is clicked
            addButton.setTag(String.valueOf(position));

            // add an onClickListener
            addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String tagName = (String) v.getTag();
                    int arrayPosition = Integer.valueOf(tagName);
                    String title =listofOrdersArray.get(arrayPosition).itemTitle;
                    int id =listofOrdersArray.get(arrayPosition).itemId;

                    // add selected item to list of selected sales parts
                    listofOrderSelectedArray.add(new ListViewsModel(id, title, ""));
                    arrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            return itemView;
        }
    };
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sales_parts, container, false);
}
}
```

I have placed the above code in 'OnActivityCreated' I am getting an error on the setOnQueryTextListener(this) line.  I have tried changing 'this' to getActivity() and getView() and neither have resolved the problem.

Comment: post your `fragment` code...

Comment: But why you added code in `onActivityCreated(..)` move all code from `onActivityCreated` to `onCreateView(....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `onCreateView(...)` like

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
 // Inflate the layout for this fragment
 View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sales_parts, container, false);

   mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.salespartsList);

  SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.typeFindSalesPart);

   ...........
 return view;
 }
```

and remove all code from `onActivityCreated(....)` and move to `onCreateView(....)`

Comment: Thanks, but this still throw an error on this line mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);  saying it cannot be applied to android.View.view

Comment: @user2029541 Apply interface like inner class/ [Go to](http://www.coderzheaven.com/tag/setonquerytextlistener/)  or [refer this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991980/actionbarsherlock-searchview-setonquerytextlistener)

Comment: @user2029541 You should  `implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` to your `Fragment`

Comment: Ah that's what I thought I would have to do, I thought fragments were meant to make development easier :/ .  Thanks M D.  I will give that a go.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use searchView like below along with a filter for the listview as in link [Android SearchView Filter ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038331/android-searchview-filter-listview)

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
         // filter listview
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```