# Android Search Using Fragments

Tags: android, search

I need to do an android search using fragments and have been looking at this:
[Android search with Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230893/android-search-with-fragments)

I have a couple of questions, however, regarding the 1st answer.

I **do not** want a new page to pop up; I want the search results to be populated within a listview of the current fragment I am within. Is that possible?

I'm not sure what code to write after:

```
 /**
 * Performs a search and passes the results to the container
 * Activity that holds your Fragments.
 */

   public void doMySearch(String query) {
    // TODO: implement this
}
```

How do I pass my results to a 'container activity' that holds my fragments? Would that be my MainActivity (that's where the code of all my fragments is located)?

Answer (score 0):

'Container Activity' doesn't specifically your `MainActivity` as this is the name a lot of devs and example code gives to their landing/home activity.

'Container Activity' refers to the `Activity` to which your `ListView` (`ListFragment`?) and Search Fragment belong.

To post the results (via your TODO code), get the parent `Activity` (`getActivity()`) and implement a method on the parent `Activity` that gets the fragment with the `ListView` and passes the data to it. You may want to have a method on the `ListView` that handles this rather than putting it on the `Activity`. (I like to think of a parent `Activity` as a delegator)