# Null pointer exception in searchview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, searchview

I am trying to create list search view in shreyaloclistfragment. I am getting NullPointerException at folowing line

```
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
```

My method is

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater ) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate( R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    System.out.println( "inflating menu");

    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();



    final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            showFilteredItems( newText );
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    return;
}
```

Stack trace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sears.syw.FragmentShopsTab.onCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentShopsTab.java:52)
at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:55)
at  


com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:559    )
at   

    com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSh    erlockNative.java:65)
at
```

Comment: So.... is `menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)` null?

Comment: Something is wrong with the inflation process such that an item with `R.id.menu_search` cannot be found. Wrong menu xml?

Comment: nope...I am trying to replicate this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230893/android-search-with-fragments)     my eml file                                                    <menu>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
    </menu>

Comment: You can't have layouts in menu xmls.

Comment: You can _reference_ layouts see answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the Appcompat library, maybe you forgot to add your own xmlns on your menu_search.xml.

As the example says:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
</menu>
```

You need to add the folowing:

```
<item android:id="+@id/..."
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
      yourapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#XML

Answer (score 4):

If you are using AppCompat library, then in your menu.xml, add

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

instead of

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

Comment: Hi. Is there a Google document stating this fact?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked in my case :)

Answer (score 3):

i am using android studio

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.app.myapp" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Buscar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

found 100%

Comment: Does that mean it's solved? Because I see in your XML the id is "search", but you are looking for "R.id.menu_search". Shouldn't that be "R.id.search"?

Comment: no, android studio configure all in u android project, no is just the xml in the menu

Answer (score 0):

To reference a layout from a menu xml use the actionLayout attribute:

```
<menu>
<item android:id="@+id/menu_name"
  android:actionLayout="@layout/your_layout"
  android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Any idea how to create list search view in fragment?

Comment: Now getting by implementing your changes                                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout     cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView
 at     com.sears.syw.FragmentShopsTab.onCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentShopsTab.    java:52)
 at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:55)
 at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:559)
 at

Answer (score 0):

Some times problem is with

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Move it from oncreate or onviewcreate to on attached method and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer
Either you are using wrong namespace or importing wrong class
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38702262/5374951