# Getting a null SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I know this already has been asked many times but I've read all of them and tried changing lot's of thing and none of them has worked.
I'm writing an app which supports only android 4 and more so I don't need support library v7 (formerly it was included though). My code is very straight forward:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchViewQueryTextListener());
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I'm getting NullPointerException on 4th line. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/AlirezaFarahani/mlearning/src) is a link to my repo so you can see anything you want. I think myself, that problems lies in `MainActivity` class or `menu.xml` or in application Manifest.

Please help, I'm stucked.

Comment: with only that to go on, we won't be able to do much, I guess.
why not checking for searchView == null
before calling a method on it?

Comment: I've put a link to entire my app!
And as I said searchView is null in 6th line.

Comment: if it is null, don't call a method on it.

Comment: You say you don't need the support library, then why are you using it? You're using `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` in your xml and `MenuItemCompat` in your code so you're clearly using the support library.

Comment: @darnmason: I've corrected that, still gets the same error

Comment: Now your repo and question are out of sync, all I can say is make sure you're importing the correct classes and either stick with the support versions or remove all references to the support library.

Comment: @darnmason: Thank you for remembering me I've updated the repo.

Comment: Probably a typo but I've seen that in your `main.xml` file you wrote `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.searchview"/>`. It should be `android.widget.SearchView` instead of `android.widget.searchview`.

Comment: @Luksprog Yes, thanks! It was as you said. Write an answer and I mark it as answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small typo in your `main.xml` menu file resource. You wrote `android.widget.searchview`, this should be `android.widget.SearchView`(case matters as there isn't any `searchview` widget in the android SDK explaining the missing(null) widget).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code is `SearchView` is not a `MenuItem` so cannot be obtained by `menu.findItem`. You have to get the menu item for search first and then get your `SearchView`.

Replace the failing line with -

```
mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
mSearchView = (EnglishVerbSearchView) MenuItemCompat.
               getActionView(mSearchMenuItem);
```

WHERE,

`R.id.action_search` is the id of your search item in the menu.

Also since you are using the compat library so your menu xml file should contain the `yourapp` namespace.

For example --

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
      yourapp:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
      yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

NOTE:

Application can be anything, in the above example as it is `yourapp`. It has to point to `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` schema though.

The typical example with account to your problem is shown at:

[Android-nullpointerexception-on-searchview-in-action-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832890/android-nullpointerexception-on-searchview-in-action-bar).

The code is included above for clarity of the problem.

**UPDATE:**

To clear your mistakes in the xml look at the following code of your xml -

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--     xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" -->

    <!-- Search / will display always -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.searchview"/>
```

Just replace the above code with the following ---

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <!-- Search / will display always -->
        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:title="@string/action_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
            yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
            yourapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.searchview"/>
```

Please note the changes in line 2, 7 and 8.

**SOURCE:** [Action View Bar.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: As I've said in the question and it's comment, I'm not gonna use v7 support library and removed it from project.

Comment: I did as your said but still get that damn exception.