# Android Searchview Causing App to Crash

Tags: java, android, android-intent, searchview

thanks for looking at this post. I am attempting to implement a search view into my android applications actionbar (I will be using Parse to store the data). I have followed google's, and few other tutorials i found online and it will not work. Every time i attempt to start the app in eclipse it crashes without opening.(it worked fine before without the searchview).

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button SubmitNewGame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Parse.initialize(this, "WQfd6X9BRu0KLpZlNoPjVVfm4AST7G9zaIy3jMUo",
                "ErxchQ7kgdw5kbhOWF1oQNfyEfjzRza2G6sRfDfb");
        SubmitNewGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitNewGame);

        SubmitNewGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        SubmitActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    /**
     * On selecting action bar icons
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            // search action
            return true;
        case R.id.action_toprated:
            // location found
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**main.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.trashed.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
     <item
        android:id="@+id/action_toprated"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_toprated"
        android:title="@string/action_toprated"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

**Trashed Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.trashed"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SubmitActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_submit"
            >
            <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value="com.example.trashed.MainActivity" />


        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.trashed.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Searchable.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

**SearchResultsActivity:**

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtQuery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);

        // get the action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        txtQuery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuery);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Handling intent data
     */
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

            /**
             * Use this query to display search results like
             * 1. Getting the data from SQLite and showing in listview
             * 2. Making webrequest and displaying the data
             * For now we just display the query only
             */
            txtQuery.setText("Search Query: " + query);

        }

    }
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
07-18 02:05:13.803: D/AndroidRuntime(2307): Shutting down VM
07-18 02:05:13.803: W/dalvikvm(2307): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad8ba8)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307): Process: com.example.trashed, PID: 2307
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at com.example.trashed.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:55)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-18 02:05:13.833: E/AndroidRuntime(2307):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please error log ?

Comment: @Haresh yes, sorry I didnt add it.

Comment: Which line in MainActivity is 55?

Comment: searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager

Answer (score 3):

You are using: `import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;` which that comes from `Support Library` and if you take look at the logcats, says:

```
at com.example.trashed.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:55)
```

The problem is coming from `MainActivity` and this method `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

**Replace your search menu with this:** from [`documentation guide`](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html)

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
     android:title="@string/action_search"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
     app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
     app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

If you are using v7 in your imports, you can't use it like this:(`android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`)

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Just replace it like [`documentation guide`](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html).

Also, `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated, use `AppCompatActivity` instead.

Instead of:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

**Try to use it like this:**

Instead:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
```

**Use:**

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
```

The important thing is: `MenuItemCompat` because you are using v7 library.

Check this question too:

[Android - NullPointerException on SearchView in Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832890/android-nullpointerexception-on-searchview-in-action-bar)

Comment: I do not see a definition for this "searchMenuItem"

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your proguard and add this line.

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Now I get an error only when submit the search on release (in debug works fine)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` use `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.SearchView"`.

Side note: Be sure to use Support Library calls instead of vanilla ones wherever necessary.