# How to set the MenuItemClickListener for a SearchView at a secondary Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

i am trying for hours to setup a simple android.support.v7.widget.SearchView in a bottom (secondary) android.support.v7.widget.ToolBar.
I am already using another Toolbar up top set up as an ActionBar, so i cannot use the `onCreateOptionsMenu` callback on activity, instead i have to set up an `OnMenuItemClickListener()` . I have read [the Android SearchView Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#create-sa), [this tutorial](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html) about Toolbars.

Related Code, 
simplified HomepageActivity

```
package something.somethingelse.activities;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnCloseListener;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class HomepageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected static final String TAG = "HomepageActivity";
private Toolbar mTopToolbar;
private Toolbar mBottomToolbar;
private FloatingActionButton mFab;
private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mTopToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.topToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mTopToolbar);


    mBottomToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.bottomToolbar);

    mBottomToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) HomepageActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = null;

            if (menuItem != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "menuItem != null");
                searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
            }

            if (searchView != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "searchView != null");
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(HomepageActivity.this.getComponentName()));
            }

            searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onClose() {
                    mBottomToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Submited: "+arg0);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Changed: "+arg0);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

    mBottomToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_toolbar);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

simplified Homepage Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:guide="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/topToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    guide:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    guide:theme="@style/Toolbar_Theme" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAb_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="58dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/generic_logo" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topToolbar" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/homepage_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/homepage_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/bottomToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/primaryDark"
            guide:elevation="4dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#60BBBBBB"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="1px" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

menu bottom_toolbar.xml

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:guide="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
    guide:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    guide:showAsAction="always">
 </item>
```

searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:hint="@string/search"
android:label="@string/app_name" 
/>
```

AndroidManifest.xml related part

```
<activity
        android:name="something.somethingelse.activities.HomepageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Default" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action     android:name="something.somethingelse.activities.HomepageActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

If i run it like that, i get a SearchView but without my `android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"`, instead i get the google SearchView icon, if i tap it i get a nice edit text, with clear and search functions, but no matter what i input or press, NONE of the Log.d inside the `Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener`gets fired up. (I cannot post images because of reputation).
If i use `android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` instead of `guide:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` i get my `android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"` , if i tap it, i get an NPE on `searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {` because `searchView` is null .

I tried doing whats on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378981/how-to-use-searchview-in-toolbar-android) related question here, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832890/android-nullpointerexception-on-searchview-in-action-bar) but no success so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated 23/09/15**
I could not find any good solution, so, since i only wanted to get the SearchView item i decided to hack into it like so:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.dlHomepageSpace, HomepageFragment.newInstance(mLanguage), HOMEPAGE_BUTTONS_TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    mSearchState = SearchState.NOSEARCH;

    mBottomToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.bottomToolbar);
    mBottomToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_toolbar);

    // Here we set the search view toolbar functions
    if(mBottomToolbar.getMenu().size() > 0){

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) HomepageActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchMenuItem = mBottomToolbar.getMenu().getItem(mBottomToolbar.getMenu().size()-1);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
        if (mSearchView != null) {
            mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(HomepageActivity.this.getComponentName()));
        }

        mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClose");
                   mBottomToolbar.getMenu().getItem(mBottomToolbar.getMenu().size()-1).collapseActionView();
                switchToFab();
                return false;
            }
        });

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMenuItem, new       MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemActionExpand");
                return true; // KEEP IT TO TRUE OR IT DOESN'T OPEN !!
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemActionCollapse");
                switchToFab();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}

@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent");
    if(isSearchAction(intent)){

        ArrayList<Detail> list = (ArrayList<Detail>) getListData(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));

        if(list.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_search_results_en, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        } else {

            ExtendedListFragment searchFragment = (ExtendedListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(HOMEPAGE_SEARCH_TAG);
            mResultsList = list;
            mSearchState = SearchState.SEARCH_LIST_SCREEN;

            if(searchFragment==null){
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.dlHomepageSpace, ExtendedListFragment.newInstance(list), HOMEPAGE_SEARCH_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } else {
                searchFragment.setDetailList(list);
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean isSearchAction(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleIntent");
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_SEARCH");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In essence, i just look into the toolbar, and obtain the one and only Item into it, i cast it as a MenuItem and then i get the SearchView as the ActionView of the MenuItem.
Like that it works and i do not have to use `setOnMenuItemClickListener()` . When i tap in the view, i can type into it (i do not need a `mSearchView.OnQueryTextListener` but, i have seen it working) , when i press the magnifying glass on the keyboard i get the `onNewIntent()` call working.

Comment: I'm also using the bottom toolbar. My implementation is almost same. But my problem is I'm not getting searchView click event. Its not going inside onMenuItemClick().

Comment: Hey, yes, at the end my implementation does not use `onMenuItemClick()` either. What do you mean that it does not get the click event? Do you mean that nothing happens when you click the magnifier glass on the keyboard? For me this triggers the `onNewIntent()` callback.

Comment: I wrote searchView textchange listener inside onMenuItemClick(). I've to remove onMenuItemClick() implementation. I've to filter RecylerView using it. On clicking magnifier glass keyboard is coming.

Comment: I'm not getting any success. Can you update your accepted answer, It will be helpful. TIA

Comment: Hey, i just updated the answer. If you have any problem, can you check that the rest of the code is the same as mine (searchable.xml, toolbar.xml, AndroidManifest.xml) ? Are you getting a toolbar with a SearchView inside?

Comment: hey dude, i had exactly the same issue as you had, i found a strange issue, maybe a bug: if you set the the  showAsAction="always|collapseActionView", listener for the search item will work, but if you set it to showAsAction="always", it wont work and you have to work on the searchview directly like "onSearchListener"

Comment: BTW: you don’t need the getItem(index), you can use `getMenu().findItem(R.id.your_menu_action_id)`