# Getting error when setting up a SearchView

Tags: java, android, view

So this I the code I use in the Activity that should get a search function:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        ***searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));***


        return true;
    }
```

I got this code from the androidDeveloper site. The two lines that I made highlighted are the ones that are making trouble.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the first answer of this post, just in case someone else has the same problem!
[Android - NullPointerException on SearchView in Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832890/android-nullpointerexception-on-searchview-in-action-bar)