# To implement search in android

Tags: android

It is the part of my code..

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    // searchManager.startSearch(oldval, selectInitialQuery, self, null, false);
    // searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

This code is used in Activity for searching.. But I need to implement this code in Fragment.. Which changes are need to be done?? How to implement Search in fragment? Please Help..

Comment: Do you want to implement search globally on the device or just a value in a some List/Grid Component?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230893/android-search-with-fragments) what you are looking for?

Comment: I just want to search value in a some list.

Answer (score 0):

create search_menu.xml
place this file in menu folder in resources

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
   yournamespace:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    yournamespace:showAsAction="always"/>
```

create activity on override onCreateOptionsMenu.

in activity write following code

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{

MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_friends_search, menu);

```
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu
                .findItem(R.id.action_search));
        AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView
                .findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
        searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        searchText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.search_hint));
        searchText.requestFocus();
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) 
            {
            }   
        });
```

}

Comment: But I need to implement searching code in Fragment, Not in Activity. Please Help. Its urgent.