# android fragmentList searchview

Tags: android, listview, fragment, searchview

hi i was wondering if is it possible to use a SearchView with a FragmentList?

i know the implementation with a Listactivity but i can get it to work with a FragmentList

this is the implementation for an activity : https://coderwall.com/p/zpwrsg/add-search-function-to-list-view-in-android
and the one from android developers website : http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see this link: http://blog.aimanbaharum.com/2014/07/android-development-8-implementing.html?

In any case you can't use SearchView in Fragment, but you can get result in Activity and then send to a fragment or update it.

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439682/3864698