# Android SearchView in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

Am having toolbar in my activity, I had tried to add Search View from Menu but am unable to add Search View in toolbar, How to add Search View in my activity toolbar.?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have done with **Fragment** by this way.

I did with **onTextChangeListener** of **search view**, just check in your **Logcat**.

**Screenshot reference:**

[image]

**menu.xml** - (`res` -> `menu`)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

**MainFragment.java**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private SearchView searchView = null;
    private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        if (searchItem != null) {
            searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        }
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

            queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    Log.i("onQueryTextChange", newText);

                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    Log.i("onQueryTextSubmit", query);

                    return true;
                }
            };
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                // Not implemented here
                return false;
            default:
                break;
        }
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Done**

Comment: Hey! I'm using your code but my search button is not expanding/showing search textedit field, any idea?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti because you forgot to add the inflater in your `OnCreateView()` , check this 

 `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);`

Comment: Not working for me! Only way to get this done in my case was with an interface: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37965747/1259763.

Comment: Works fine even when you assign OnQueryTextListener in onCreateOptionsMenu() so you don't have to override onOptionsItemSelected().

Answer (score 3):

menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

\res\xml\searchable.xml:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.searchview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

[image]