# Add items to android toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

In my activity_main.xml i have this toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#770000ff"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">



    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In Manifest there is that in `<application>` :

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

In `res/values/style.xml` i have 
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

The `MainActivity.java` file is that:

```
import ... ;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    }
}
```

Now, the toolbar has only the application name and nothing else.
How can i add items with icon such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/y29jV.png ?

Comment: The icon on the right appears when you add menu to your activity. The icon on the right appears when you add a Navigation drawer to your activity(icon is set inside Navigation drawer code).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489109/android-searchview-in-toolbar might help you.

Comment: @AkhilSoman means the icon on the LEFT appears when you add a Navigation Drawer. ;) :)

Comment: The icon on the left is not a static icon. It is dynamically rendered using DrawerArrowDrawableToggle class. But if you want to add a static icon then this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071763/toolbar-navigation-hamburger-icon-missing) might help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### First a Menu xml file and Put it in res/menu folder

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        ></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_user"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="User"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_user"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>

</menu>
```

### Add These methods in Activity File

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Where should i put menu.xml file?

Answer (score 10):

Or you can add needed items in your xml file like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
android:background="@color/blue"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/toolbar_margin"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_back"
        style="@style/toolbar_imageview_back"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        style="@style/toolbar_title"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_inbox_edit"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

The icon on the left is used for navigation, and can be customized by

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icon_to_be_used);
```

The icons on the right are created by creating an [XML menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)in /res/menu/ and then inflating it in the activity using:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    ></item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_user"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:title="User"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_user"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>

</menu>
```

And in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add items to your menu like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/search"
    appcompat:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_profile"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/action_profile"
    app:showAsAction="never"
   />


 </menu>
```

And then in your activity add :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

That's It.

Comment: So, should I put the xml code in a different xml file and not in activity_main.xml?

Comment: That's right, @ScTALE. Menus go in /res/menu - read about them here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 0):

There is menu resource file present in app>src>main>res>menu.menu.main file. There you need to add the items you want to display ,like

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/any_Id"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="ANY_TITLE"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Then in your activity code , use these two methods

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.any_Id: //Your task
            return true;

        default:return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```