# Adding search functionality inside a tabbed-acitivity in Android

Tags: android, listview, searchview

I've checked [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301738/how-to-filter-listview-using-searchview-in-an-activity-when-the-list-view-is-in) where I basically have the same issue.

The difference is that I am not using an **Adapter Class** in my project, I only have a **TabActivity.java** (android studio default) that populated my fragments.

I have already followed all the steps in the questions answer however I do not understand the third step.

**3.Code of Adapter(Adapter_Contacts.java in my case)**

Where should I put this code because in my case I do not use any Adapter Class

this is my fragment adapter inside tabactivity.java

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new BrowseTitle();
            case 1:
                return new ChatHistory();
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

and this is one of my fragment that populated inside tabactivity

```
public class BrowseTitle extends Fragment {

private DatabaseReference mRootRef;


private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> list_of_thread = new ArrayList<>();
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
//Overriden method onCreateView
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browse_title, container, false);
    //this is the logic
    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tdesc");
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleList);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list_of_thread){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            //changin text color
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            return view;
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
public void beginSearch(String query) {
        Log.e("QueryFragment", query);
        arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
    }
```

}

Is there a way I can implement this correctly?

Comment: Please provide some code. Do you want to filter the list inside the fragment? If yes, you need to put that code inside the adapter of the lists inside the tabs.

Comment: @jonathanrz i will provide the code in just a second, yes i want to filter inside the fragment.

Comment: @jonathanrz so did you mean i need to add the code inside every fragment?

Comment: @A N Syafig Yes, you have an ArrayAdapter, you need to create a custom class that extends the ArrayAdapter, add the code in it and use it instead of the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @jonathanrz is there any other solution instead of creating a new class?, because i have few fragments and i dont want to rewrite everything.