# Cannot filter audio files inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, audio, filtering

Hi I am VERY new to android and Java, please have mercy. I want to filter ListView items inside different fragments using the SearchView in action bar. I am using a custom Array Adapter. There are one ImageView, two TextViews and an audio file attached to each ListView item. It plays the audio when the user clicks on the item. I have implemented [How to filter listview using Searchview in an activity when the list view is in fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301738/how-to-filter-listview-using-searchview-in-an-activity-when-the-list-view-is-in) in my app and I am able to get correct results but the audio files are not filtered. Any thoughts?

EDITED

It turns out I was getting an item from the original list.

Comment: the problem is in your code. I'm 100% sure. But you didn't show it.

Comment: The problem is in the OnItemClickListener. How can I get access mWordFilterList.get(position) inside the listener?

Comment: ok, but how exactly you expect to filter it by audio? As for the text - you enter the text, and it shows only items that contain that text, but how should it filter by audio?

Comment: Thanks my question wasn't clear. I did a little more research and I found out that I am getting an item from the original list and I think I know the direction to fix it. Thanks!