# Navigate to a Fragment of another Activity by SearchActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

In my App I'm using the [Android Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation).
My MainActivity has a NavigationGraph and I can navigate properly. Since I also need to implemend Search functionality I added a [SearchActivity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#UsingSearchWidget) with a SearchFragment. The Search shows a RecyclerView with the Resultset. When I click one of these Results I want to navigate to the specific Fragment of MainActivity.

Unfortunately the App just Navigates to the first Fragment of MainActivity. How do I navigate to a Fragment of another Activity?

NavGraph of MainActivity:
[image: NavGraph of MainActivity]

NavGraph of SearchActivity:
[image: NavGraph of SearchActivity]

I navigate to the Fragment of MainActivity by this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putInt(SessionFragment.ARG_PARAM1, mSessions.get(position).session.getId());
navController.navigate(R.id.sessionFragment, bundle);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: NavigationComponent recommends using one Activity and multiple fragments. Why do you want to create separate Activity for Search and not a Fragment?

Comment: You would not be having this problem if there weren't multiple Activities in the first place. Now you'd have to add a new Activity just to be able to start this Fragment as its first fragment.

Comment: I use Fragments for the MainActivity and want to stick to the Recommendations by NavigationComponent. But the Docs about Search describe to create a Searchable Activity: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#SearchableActivity This SO Question points out that Search inside of a Fragment is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230893/android-search-with-fragments

Answer (score 0):

I ended up configuring my MainActivity as SearchableActivity and pass the SearchQuery to a SearchFragment.

AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Then on the MainActivity I check for the SearchIntent and navigate to it with the Query as Argument:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    NavDirections action = HomeFragmentDirections.showSearch(
       intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY)
    );
    navController.navigate(action);
}
```

In my SearchFragment I handle the Search as described by the Google Docs.
This may not be the best solution, but works.